# Encode my multiclass classification problem for ordinal NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, multiclass-classification

I want to encode my multiclass classification output variable in a specific way to take ordinality into account. I want to use this in a NN with sigmoid objective.
[image]

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. How could I encode my classes in this way?
2. This would not change the problem from multiclass to multilabel classification right?

P.S. here is a [link](http://orca.st.usm.edu/%7Ezwang/files/rank.pdf) to the paper I based this on. And here is a figure representing the change from a normal NN to their addaptation:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

**1. How could I encode my classes in this way?**
Depends on the framework, a pytorch example can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-ordinal-regression-classification-in-pytorch-361a2a095a99), which also includes a code snippet for converting from predictions and back to labels

**This would not change the problem from multiclass to multilabel classification right?**
No, you would have multiple binary outputs, but they are subsequently converted to a single label, thus it is still multiclass classification.